# Lambda Collector throwing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Lambda expression intermittently throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in my Impl.java class.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Impl.lambda$retrieve$0(Impl.java:124) ~[classes/:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at Impl.retrieve(Impl.java:125) ~[classes/:?]
```

I've written a sample program simulating the scenario. But, in the sample program, it is NOT reproducible. However, can someone figure out any problem with the following code?

I've tried with empty/non-empty input. When I make numberStr to throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, the stack trace appears different:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at LambdaTest.lambda$0(LambdaTest.java:13)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at LambdaTest.main(LambdaTest.java:14)
```

Sample program:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.commons.math3.util.Pair;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class LambdaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] numberStr = { "one", "two", "three" };
        List<Pair<String, SampleEnum>> result = getInputPairs().stream()
                .map(entry -> new Pair<String, SampleEnum>(numberStr[entry.getFirst()], entry.getSecond()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // <=== similar to Impl.java:125
        System.out.println("Lambda tested." + result.toString());
    }

    private static List<Pair<Integer, SampleEnum>> getInputPairs() {
        List<Pair<Integer, SampleEnum>> pairs = Lists.newArrayList();
        //pairs.add(new Pair<Integer, SampleEnum>(0, SampleEnum.ONE_AND_ONLY));
        return pairs;
    }

}

enum SampleEnum {
    ONE_AND_ONLY
}
```

In what cases, can the expression fail? and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean with “different”? These stack traces look basically identical. Whether the synthetic method holding the body of your lambda expression is named `LambdaTest.lambda$0` or `Impl.lambda$retrieve$0` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Holger Great! Got it. It is same. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `numberStr[entry.getFirst()]` is throwing the error. In your `Impl` class, `numberStr` somehow has too few elements. Either use a debugger or put this before the `.stream()` line to see what's going on:

```
System.out.println("numberStr: " + Arrays.toString(numberStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

On the same line as Sean mentioned
 `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`
This exception clearly tells the that while fetching the data from Array for 1st element, it failed.

If you fix this then it should work fine. To see more clearly, setup debugger at numberStr and see how many elements are there and check how many elements you get from stream. If you try to access an index which is not available in your array. You should see this exception